# In Gaussian processes what is the difference between the marginal likelihood and the predictive likelihood on the training set?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, machine-learning, regression, bayesian

Are these the same thing? I understand the marginal likelihood is the predictive likelihood over the prior, but since the GP the prior is defined on the training set, are these the same thing? Can we show it mathematically?

Comment: [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147513/marginal-likelihood-vs-prior-predictive-probability#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20predict,prior%20predictive%20distribution%20has%20a) is relevant.

Comment: Thanks! So it appears the answer is Yes